# android длительное нажатие кнопки

Tags: java, android, button

Как сделать кнопку, которая должна запустить выполнение метода только после удержания данной кнопки три секунды, и показать сообщение, что метод запущен, а если не прошло трёх секунд, то ничего не делать?

Answer (score 7):

Можно как-то так: назначаем слушатель прикосновений, при начале прикосновения замеряем время начала прикосновения, в момент отпускания считаем сколько прошло времени с начала прикосновения.

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){

    long startTime;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // нажатие
              startTime = System.currentTimeInMills();
              break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // движение
              break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // отпускание
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:  
              long totalTime = System.currentTimeInMills() - startTime;
              long totalSecunds = totalTime / 1000;
              if( totalSecunds >= 3 )
              {
                  //ВОТ тут прошло 3 или больше секунды с начала нажатия
                  //можно что-то запустить
                  System.out.println("Три секунды прошло с нажатия!");
              }
              break;
          }
          return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете попробовать использовать Touch Listener:

```
    Handler handel = new Handler();
    b.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            switch (arg1.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                handel.postDelayed(run, 3000);
                break;

            default:
                handel.removeCallbacks(run);
                break;

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

b -  это view, в вашем варианте должна быть кнопка нажатие которой вы хотите отслеживать.

run:

```
Runnable run = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Your code to run on long click

    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Button button = new Button();
long then = 0;
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            then = (Long) System.currentTimeMillis();
        } else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            if(((Long) System.currentTimeMillis() - then) >= 3000){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то к `then` доступа не будет внутри слушателя, т.к. переменная не финальная. А если её сделать финальной, то её нельзя переназначить. В моём ответе, вроде, должно быть решение сей проблемы.